# Filtering Array WithIn Array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, array-filter

I have the following JSON structure.

```
comapany : XYZ
Emp Info:[
            {
                empName: A,
                empID:1
                salary[
                    {
                        year: 2017,
                        value: 3000
                    },
                    {
                        year: 2018,
                        value: 5000
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                empName: B,
                empID:2
                salary[
                    {
                        year: 2017,
                        value: 6000
                    },
                    {
                        year: 2018,
                        value: 3000
                    }
                ]
            },
        {
            empName: C,
            empID:3
            salary[
                {
                    year: 2017,
                    value: 3000
                },
                {
                    year: 2018,
                    value: 8000
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

Here Emp Info is an array and inside this contains another array of salaries. 
I want to filter all the salaries which have value of 3000. So my output should look like below

```
comapany : XYZ
Emp Info:[
            {
                empName: A,
                empID:1
                salary[
                    {
                        year: 2017,
                        value: 3000
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                empName: B,
                empID:2
                salary[
                    {
                        year: 2018,
                        value: 3000
                    }
                ]
            },
        {
            empName: C,
            empID:3
            salary[
                {
                    year: 2017,
                    value: 3000
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

I have tried multiple things using lodash, but it always returns all the data(and not filtering).

```
._filter(data, data => {
     return data.empInfo.salary[0].value === 3000
});

._each(data.empInfo.salary, data => {
     _.filter(data, d=>{
        return d.salary === 3000;
     });
});

._filter(data.empInfo.salary, data => {
    _.each(salary, s => {
        return s === 3000;
    });
});
```

Can someone help in filtering this json preferably using lodash

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add your relevant code attempts to your question as [mcve]s.

Comment: The the example that I have given is a dummy example, but similar to the JSON structure that I am dealing with. Hence I have not included examples of my code attempts

Comment: I'm talking about "I have tried multiple things using lodash". What things have you tried? Add _that_ code to your question.

Comment: Updated with few of my attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let newEmpInfo = empInfo.map( info => {
   return { ... info, salary: info.salary.filter( salary => salary.value === 3000 )};
});
```

That's the easiest way, no need for lodash. Simple array operations in JS.

As a side note, you should add your coding attempts next time, as usually in SO this kinds of questions where people just come here so we can solve their problems are un-welcomed and usually gets a lot of downvotes.

Comment: Thanks. That worked.I was not able to think of using map.

Comment: I did not added any of my attempted code snippets is because the JSON i have provided is a dummy json but with similar structure. Although now I have added my code examples. I will take care of this from the next time Thanks

Comment: @SoumyajeetNayak np :)
Also, if this works for you please tick the green V near the answer so other users know this question is a;ready answered